# Program running in NetBeans but not command prompt

Tags: java, import

I am trying to design and implement a Java class to represent a 3-D geometric shape. The class should contain a constructor, appropriate data fields and methods to return the volume of the shape, and the surface area of the shape and any other methods that seem to make sense for your shape.

However, I got everything to work fine in Net Beans, but when I try to run it in the command prompt I receive:

```
error package Cube doesn't exist

error cannot find symbol
```

both of these error are referring to the class cube

My code is as follows.

```
package cube;


public class Cube {
    private double side = 0.0;

    public Cube(){//begin constructor
        side = 1.0;
    }//end constructor

    public void setSide (double length) {//begin method
        side = length;
    }//end method

    public double getSide () {//begin method
        return side;
    }//end method

    public double calculateVolume() {
        double volume2 = side * side * side;
        return volume2;
    } // end method

    public double calculateSurfaceArea() {
        double area = 6 * (side * side);
        return area;
    } // end method
}//end class





package randygilmanhw4;

import java.util.Scanner;
import cube.Cube;//imports class Cube

public class RandyGilmanHW4 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {//begin main
        //Display welcome message
        System.out.println("Hello Welcome to Randy's Cube");
        System.out.println("      Calculator Program");
        System.out.println("");
        Cube one = new Cube();
        //declare variables within main
        double area;
        double volume2;
        double side1;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a length of the side of the cube in cm: ");
        side1 = input.nextDouble();
        one.setSide(side1);
        volume2 = one.calculateVolume();
        System.out.printf("Cube's volume is: %4.2f cm^3", volume2);// OUTPUT
        System.out.println("\n");

        one.setSide(side1);
        area = one.calculateSurfaceArea();
        System.out.printf("Cube's surface area is: %4.2f cm^2 ", area);// OUTPUT
    } // end main    

}//end class
```

Comment: Your package is `c`ube not `C`ube, i.e. starting with lowercase `c`!

Comment: If the problem isn't what A4L pointed out, share the "java" command you are running at the command line.

Comment: What do you mean by "share" the java command when I try to compile it in command prompt, I input javac RandyGilmanHW4.java, then it gives me all those errors?

Comment: Not the `javac` command used to *compile*, the `java` command used to *run*

Answer (score 0):

Simple - when you save it into a .java file, remove the line "package cube;" and save.  It should now work - "package" is used for your IDE, not with notepad/cmd prompt.  Save your file as RandyGilmanHW4.java